# variable set used by awk in bash

Tags: bash, variables, awk

whether I use colNb or $colNb, it doesn't work

```
export colNb=$(awk '{print NF}' file1 | sort -nu | tail -n 1)

awk '{for(i=3 ; i<colNb; i++) {printf("%s\t", $i)} print ""}' file1 | less
```

with $colNb, I get

```
awk: illegal field $(), name "colNb"
 input record number 1, file1
 source line number 1
```

and with colNb, I just get empty fields instead of the fields in file1

Comment: You really need to learn the difference between a variable (`colNb`) and a field (`$<number>`) if you're going to be doing anything at all in awk. `colNb` is a variable that could contain a numer, say `3`. `$3` is the value of input field number 3. `$colNb` is the value of the input field at the position indicated by the contents of variable `colNb` so since `colNb` contains the value `3`, `$colNb` is the same as `$3`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-v` option in awk to pass shell variables to awk:

```
awk -v colNb="$colNb" '{for(i=3 ; i<colNb; i++) {printf("%s\t", $i)} print ""}' file1 | less
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
awk '{for(i=3 ; i<c; i++) {printf("%s\t", $i)} print ""}' c="$colNb" file1 | less
```

You need to set variable outside awk with `-v` or after awk